# C++ rewriting nested if else statement with a function

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm working on a program that prints all numbers divisible by itself. I'm trying to avoid repetition in my code with if else statements. I want to turn this bit of code to adapt to whatever number is entered. 
I have tried doing

```
while ( x % x == 0)
```

but it just returns every number.
I have also tried

```
int& x = y
```

to copy `x` and use `x % y`, but it's the same as `x % x`.

```
else if(x == y)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << endl;

    while(x <= 1000)
    {
        y = x;

        while(x % y == 0)
        {
            cout << x << " ";
            break;
        }

        x++;
    }
}
else if(x == 2)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << endl;

    while(x <= 1000)
    {
        y = x;

        while(x % y == 0)
        {
            cout << x << " ";
            break;
        }

        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do know that the modulo operator is a division, right? And what is the result of dividing something with itself? Then think a little bit about that `x % 1` expression, what is *anything* divided by `1`?

Comment: Last time I checked, the physical laws of this universe require every number to be divisible by itself, and "x % x" will always return 0, for any number x (except 0 itself). Which you have successfully proven. Congratulations.

Comment: Don't store the multiple of x in the same place as x. You can copy the present value of x into a different integer y with `int y = x;` There's more that's wrong with this program to print multiples of a number than just that, though.

Comment: I'd say that your description of what you want your program to do is completely wrong. You don't want to find all the numbers that can be divided by themselves (which would be pretty useless, since all can), but rather, you want to find all the numbers which can be divided by 1 (ok, all of them), then all those that can be divided by 2 (=all the even numbers), then I guess you would like to continue with those that can be divided by 3, 4, and so on.

Comment: I just posted the sniplet of it. X is entered by thr user so if they entered 5 it would print out every number to 1000 that 5 could be divided into evenly. So if x = 5 it should be 5%5. 5 10 15 20 ect

Comment: I still don't get what you want to do. `x` is entered by the user (by the way, this was not really clear), ok. So let's say he enters 5. What is the output that you expect? All multiples of 5 from 1 to 1000, that is: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, ..., 990, 995, 1000? For the record, `5%5` is 0.

Comment: If one of the answers below solved your problem, please don't forget to accept it!

Answer (score 2):

```
int &x = y;
```

does not perform a copy, it's a reference (read about that). With that, `y` refers to the memory location of `x`, so it has the same value. You need a copy (`x` and `y` being independent of each other), so it must be

```
int x = y; // so easy?
```

OK, but you wrote it the other way around to mess things up a bit. So, it should be

```
int y = x;

if(x % y == 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/**
 * prints number from x to 1000 that are divisible by x
 * @param x divisor
 */
void print_divisible_to_1k(int x)
{
    using namespace std;

    int i = x; /* from i to 1000 */

    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << endl;

    while ( i <= 1000 )
    {
        if ( i % x == 0 ) /* use if statement not while loop */
        {
            cout << i << " ";
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's a more problem aware version of the solution, thanks @Jarod42:

```
/**
 * prints number from x to 1000 that are divisible by x
 * @param x divisor
 */
void print_divisible_to_1k(int x)
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << endl;

    /* a more problem-aware programming solution via @Jarod42 */
    for ( int i = x; i <= 1000; i += x)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of `if` with `for (int i = x; i <= 1000; i += x) {std::cout << i <<" "; }`

Comment: @Jarod42, Nice optimization, added, thanks! Though if this is for homework, he's probably better off not using that one without a more fundamental knowledge of conditionals/loops.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 int main()
{
  int n, i, flag=0;
  cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
  cin >> n;
  for(i=2;i<=n/2;++i)
  {
      if(n%i==0)
      {
          cout << "This is divisible by "+i;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants. You are testing whether a number `n` is prime; I think the wants to find all the multiples of `n`. That's very different. Anyway... "This is a prime number and is divisible by itself"? *All* numbers are divisible by themselves, including non-primes. Which to me indicates that this is not what the OP really wants.